# IMCE and user privileges

Tags: files

I have a taxonomy like this in our Drupal 7 website.

```
(Group1)
 |
 +---- (Group1SubGroup1)
 +---- (...)
 +---- (Group1SubGroup10)

(Group2)
 |
 +---- (Group2SubGroup1)
 +---- (...)
 +---- (Group2SubGroup4)
 ...
```

And we've use a module (I dont remember the name) that gives users rights depending on the term. For example, for `user1` we give him CRUD rights on `Group2SubGroup4`, but nothing on `Group2SubGroup1`.

There's a shared directory where you can upload media files when you create an article.

So, when the `user1` want to create a new article with term `Group2SubGroup4`, we'd like to  give him rights to upload a file, but ***only*** in a sub-directory of the "shared multimedia files directory" called `Group2SubGroup4`.

For example if the directory is `/www/htdocs/multimedia`, when the `user1` want to create a new article with term `Group2SubGroup4`, he will have rights to upload multimedia files but its "base" directory will be `/www/htdocs/multimedia/Group2SubGroup4`

How would you do this?

And if you have an easy solution for this, I'd like to do more: have the rights to write on the right directory (`/www/htdocs/multimedia/Group2SubGroup4`) ***and*** still the possibility to read everything else (`/www/htdocs/multimedia` and other subdirectories). How would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy: it's already integrated in Drupal. Just activate the `media` module and go to `Administration->Configuration->Media` and there's a very, very, **very²²³** powerful IMCE configuration panel.